# Changing Background Colours

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, html-select

I'm currently trying to change the background colour in all my pages using the template. In my footer, I have an html `select` element. I'm trying to use JavaScript to let the user choose a colour and then update it. However it's not updating the colour at all. Could you have a look at my code and tell me what I'm missing, many thanks!

HTML:

```
<form id="frmAccess" onClick="changeBackground()">
  <select id="colourSelected" name="backgroundColour">
    <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
    <option value="Green">Green</option>
    <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="Pink">Pink</option>
    <option value="White">White/Default</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Update Colour"/>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    background-color: #FFF;
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 0;
}

.containerYellow {
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    background-color: #FF6;
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 0;
}

.containerGreen {
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    background-color: #3F9;
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 0;
}

.containerBlue {
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    background-color: #0CF;
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 0;
}

.containerPink {
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    background-color: #FCF;
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 0;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function changeBackground()
{
    var selectedColour = document.getElementById('colourSelected').value;

    switch(selectedColour)
    {
        case Yellow: document.getElementById('container').className = "containerYellow";
        break;
        case Green: document.getElementById('container').className = "containerGreen";
        break;
        case Blue: document.getElementById('container').className = "containerBlue";
        break;
        case Pink: document.getElementById('container').className = "containterPink";
        break;
        case White: document.getElementById('container').className = "container";
    }//end switch

}//end function
```

Comment: The container is a class, not an id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default behavior when a form is submitted is to post data. To prevent this, we need to call `event.preventDefault()` on the form. Call it after listening for the `submit` event on the form element.

Take a look at the code snippet.

```js
var updateColor = document.getElementById("colour-update");
var form = document.getElementById("frmAccess");

form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var select = document.getElementById("colourSelected");
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = select.value;
});
```

```html
    <form id="frmAccess" onClick="changeBackground()">
            <select id="colourSelected" name="backgroundColour">
                <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
                <option value="Green">Green</option>
                <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
                <option value="Pink">Pink</option>
                <option value="White">White/Default</option>
             </select>
             <input type="submit" id="colour-update" value="Update Colour"/>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can store a user's selection inside a variable by use of `prompt`.

```
var color = prompt("select a color");

document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your working code :

```
<html>

<body id="container">
<style>
.container {
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    background-color: #FFF;
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 0;
}

.containerYellow {
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    background-color: #FF6;
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 0;
}

.containerGreen {
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    background-color: #3F9;
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 0;
}

.containerBlue {
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    background-color: #0CF;
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 0;
}

.containerPink {
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    background-color: #FCF;
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 0;
}
</style>
    <select id="colourSelected" name="backgroundColour">
        <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
        <option value="Green">Green</option>
        <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
        <option value="Pink">Pink</option>
        <option value="White">White/Default</option>
     </select>
     <input type="button" value="Update Colour" onClick="changeBackground()"/>

<script>
function changeBackground()
{  
    var selectedColour = document.getElementById('colourSelected').value;

    switch(selectedColour)  
    {
        case "Yellow": document.getElementById('container').setAttribute("class","containerYellow");
        break;
        case "Green": document.getElementById('container').setAttribute("class","containerGreen");
        break;
        case "Blue": document.getElementById('container').setAttribute("class","containerBlue");
        break;
        case "Pink": document.getElementById('container').setAttribute("class","containterPink");
        break;
        case "White": document.getElementById('container').setAttribute("class","container");
    }//end switch

}//end function
</script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Storing the colors hexa in value is a good idea here.
I hope this is what you expected:

```js
function changeBackground() {
  document.getElementById('container').style.backgroundColor = event.srcElement.value;

}
```

```css
#container {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  background-color: #FFF;
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 0;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

</div>
<form id="frmAccess">
  <select id="colourSelected" name="backgroundColour" onchange="changeBackground()">
    <option selected disabled="" value="">Please select a color</option>
    <option value="#fff400">Yellow</option>
    <option value="#09ff00">Green</option>
    <option value="#0038ff">Blue</option>
    <option value="#ff00f4">Pink</option>
    <option value="#ffffff">White/Default</option>
  </select>
</form>
```